# GAv4 for android: can deviceCategory value be overriden?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

I need to manually override the value that Google analytics sends for the `deviceCategory` predefined user dimension (let's say that instead of "mobile", I need It to be "android phone"). But I couldn't find anywhere in the SDK documentation if this is possible or not, and how to do it, other than using a custom dimension, which is not what I want.

Is this even possible?

Comment: you can't thins is added by the sdks there is no way to override it

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely override some of the default dimensions as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens) You could probably follow the same algo to override other dimensions.

Another thing I'd try is looking at the network request and seeing if `deviceCategory` can be overriden by setting it as an event propery.

Finally, you can always override any field if you use GTM inbetween, but it's  kind of an overkill. You don't want to use it just to slightly shift the field value.

I would generally suggest either not touching it at all if you're just renaming it for the comfort of the analyst or using a custom dimension/event propery to track it if it's a separate datapoint.